# jQuery: Remove a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a function from a plugin looking like this …

```
$('.parallax-sections').parallax();
```

I want this function to be responsing in the onResize event and only be applied my window is larger than 700px.

```
$(window).on("resize", function (e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 700) {
        // remove or disable this function again ???
        //$('.parallax-sections').parallax();
    } else {
        $('.parallax-sections').parallax();
    }
});
```

Comment: The plugin itself should provide a _destroy/disable_ option. Refer to documentations.

Comment: The code you showed us is doing what you are asking. The `.parallax()` function will be applied only if the windows is larger than 700px. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: But if the window is larger, and I resize it down under 700 it is still applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can `disable` and `enable` it.

```
$('.parallax-sections').parallax();

$(window).on("resize", function(e) {

    if ($(window).width() < 700) {
        $('.parallax-sections').parallax('disable');
    } else {
        $('.parallax-sections').parallax('enable');
    }

});
```

[**DOCS**](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax#jquery-api)